# Use EventEmitters with programmatically instantiated modal

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've created a modal to add a piece of data to an object (object view is parent view), but I'm struggling to find out i would pass that I've created a new piece of subdata/the subdata itself back to the parent window.

Its on a button click within the modal that I make a REST POST call, which then closes the modal window - I either need to pass the sub data back to display in the list of subdata's within the object view, or pick up when the modal closes in order to refresh the main data source in the object view.

I'm struggling to get anything working because you can't hook into the EventEmitters because the modal isn't declared in the template, its created on button press with a modal controller.

All help/ideas are appreciated.

Code for modal creation below:

```
import { NavController, NavParams, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) { }

updateObject() {
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ObjectUpdateView, {
  item: this.object,
  viewType: this.viewType
});
modal.present();


}
```

Comment: which modal you have used?  Please show some piece of code

Comment: @ER.SHASHITIWARI I've added code snippet

Comment: EventEmitter isn't related to the template. Create your event emitter in your original component and pass it in to the modal and then subscribe/emit